# Narrow wallpaper column

Tags: wallpaper

The wall I am applying wallpaper, which comes in 20-1/2" rolls, will require 13 whole width columns and two that are around 13-1/4", primarily because of the pattern. I have seen some videos but did not see a scenario like mine. My question is, when applying a column that is narrow, do I rip my column to something like an inch wider than the width, for wiggle room, and then trim the edge when applying or can I just post the column with the whole width and then have 7+ inches of slack and cut it then. Basically, is it easier to work with less slack that will have to be trimmed once the final position has been adjusted?

Comment: How good do you measure?  More wiggle room is required for not good measurements.  Having extra to trim is better than too less.

Comment: Nice to know my wife isn't the only one left who likes wallpaper